# how to draw transparent gradual color

Tags: android, colors

in my code :

```
paint.setColor(Color.GRAY);
paint.setAlpha(80);
canvas.drawPath(getPath2(), paint);

public static Path getPath2()
{
    Path mPath2 = new Path();



    mPath2.moveTo(pta2.x, pta2.y);
    mPath2.lineTo(pta.x, pta.y);

    mPath2.lineTo(ptb.x, ptb.y);

     mPath2.quadTo(ptl.x, ptl.y, ptd.x, ptd.y);

    mPath2.close();
    return mPath2;
}
```

you know my paint draw a gray,it is not transparent,and  gradual change,i donot know if i should use paint.setColorFilter, can you tell me how to do

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setStyle(Style.FILL);
LinearGradient gradient = new LinearGradient(fromx, fromy, tox, toy, new int[]{color1, color2, color3}, new float[]{0, 0.6f, 1}, TileMode.CLAMP);
paint.setShader(gradient);
canvas.drawPath(getPath2(), paint);
```

Comment: are you other method ,in your method have fromx, fromy, tox, toy,because my path is dynamic change.

Comment: The code above is just a sample, fromx fromy tox toy indicates the direction which gradient should apply to. You can get path bounds by calling computeBounds of the Path class